# Use Home PC without a public IP as a VPN server

Tags: linux, vpn, reverse-proxy

I have a PC at home. I want to route my laptop's traffic through my home PC.

How can I set up a remote live server (an AWS EC2 instance) with VPN, so my laptop can connect to it. Then it routes the requests to its other client (my home PC), and it is sent to the internet from my home PC.

Comment: You must provide the work you did before asking people to work for free to do this. Because here you're asking everything rather than asking for help on a problem you got.

Comment: @A.B I need guidance. If it is achievable? What tools can be used to achieve this? Can OpenVPN be configured this way? Just show me the path and I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

you should give us a lil more info on what operating system the pc is using but im guessing you are using ubuntu linux or smth.

`nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid mywifi password "mypassword"`

and then you should plug in your ethernet cable into the wifi access point

`ifconfig eth0 up`

and then test the connection on your labtop by connecting to the hotspot and testing it with

`ping google.com`

and then that should work. but nextime if you are trying to do something and you dont have a problem **dont ask**. you couldve easily shearced it up yourself
instead of making us do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).